# Sumar variables dentro de un archivo.txt con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Tengo un archivo llamado numeros.txt que es asi

```
Transaccion 2001
var monto= "25000"

Transaccion 2002
var monto= "28000"

Transaccion 2003
var monto= "66000"

Transaccion 2004
var monto= "30000"

Transaccion 2005
var monto= "85000"
```

Y tengo un archivo index.html en el cual quiero que se sumen todos los **"var monto"** sin identificar uno por uno ya que el archivo va creciendo con cada operacion a traves del sistema ejemplo 2001,2002,2003,2004..

Quisiera que se hiciera una suma general de esa variable **monto**

Answer (score 0):

En vez de un txt, yo crearía un `JSON`, de esta manera sumo los `montos` con [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).

```js
let obj = [

{"Transaccion": 2001,
"monto": 25000},

{"Transaccion": 2002,
"monto": 28000},

{"Transaccion": 2003,
"monto": 66000},

{"Transaccion": 2004,
"monto": 30000},

{"Transaccion": 2005,
"monto": 85000}

];


let montoTotal = obj.reduce(function(sum,value){
  
  return sum+value.monto
  
},0);

console.log(montoTotal);
```